# How to change the user look point in a FORM window

Tags: c#

Hello surfers of Stackoverflow, before I ask my question, I will explain the need of the question.
I'm working on developing a 2D platform game to learn and experiment with game development.

What I'm trying to do is building a map that is bigger than the borders limits of the FORM window and my player will be in the middle of the FORM window by having the rest of the objects move around it.

In my opinion, the way that games are built is that they do not move an object and change the position, perhaps the object remains in its own position, and the player changes its position "and the camera follows it"

I searched in the internet to see how to do it and unfortunately did not find an answer, all I found was around the unity environment, which did not fit my case.

You can view these images to understand the result I'm trying to reach:

[image]

We take userlook (x, y) and assume that when it is called it places this point in the middle of the FORM window.

now when i'll change userlook and player.position to:

```
x = 100
y = -50
```

the result will be something like :

[image]

Is there any way to do something similar to what I've done here?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. It would be beneficial to work with "world coordinates" in your code. You'll want a way to translate world coordinates into "viewport coordinates" which would be the visible area on the form.

Comment: @itsme86 That's exactly what I meant, but I can not find any information about "worldcoordinates/viewport coordinates" in order to learn about it and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty old but still maybe it can help some people out.
What I've tried to achive here is a way that I can move around and make a camera that follow my account.
The trick is when we move around the player will still be in the middle of the screen and all the other obstacles will change there position according to him.

So basically you need to create a class that will be a Camera / Viewport controller or any other name you want to give it.

Set coordinates to the class

```
class Camera {

public static int x = 0, y = 0;

public static void setX(int set) {
this.x = set;
}

public static void setY(int set) {
this.y = set;
}

public static int getX() {
return this.x;
}

public static int getY() {
return this.y;
}

}
```

now for any obstacle you have in the map that you want to update there X position, you need to set the position to X + Camera.x

the main character / object should not be effected from Camera and should not move at all.
the controllers you are settings should change only the Camera we created.

Hope it gave you some light. I couldn't get it when I started.